# id для адресной строки (url)

Tags: php

Код ниже должен отображать id пользователя из mysql, который входит на страницу под своим логином, но в адресную строку выводит id=Resource id #5, в чем может быть ошибка?

login.php

```
  <?php
include_once("bd.php");
if (isset($_POST['login'])){
    $login = $_POST['login'];
    if ($login == '') {
        unset($login);
        exit ("Введите пожалуйста логин!");
    }
}
if (isset($_POST['password'])){
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    if ($password == '') {
        unset($password);
        exit ("Введите пароль");
    }
}
$login = stripslashes($login);
$login = htmlspecialchars($login);
$password = stripslashes($password);
$password = htmlspecialchars($password); 
$login = trim($login);
$password = trim($password);
$password = md5($password);
$user = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE login='$login' AND password='$password'");
$id_user = mysql_fetch_array($user);

if (empty($id_user['id'])){
    exit ("Извините, введённый вами логин или пароль неверный.<a href='index.php'>назад</a><br>");

}
else {
    $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
    $_SESSION['login'] = $login;
    $_SESSION['id'] = $id_user['id'];
    $id_user = $_GET['id'];
$qq = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $user");
$id_user = mysql_fetch_row($user);
 echo "<meta http-equiv='Refresh' content='0; URL=index.php?id=$user'>";
  }          
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделайте

```
else {
  $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
  $_SESSION['login'] = $login;
  $_SESSION['id'] = $id_user['id'];
  echo "< meta http-equiv='Refresh' content='0; URL=index.php?id={$id_user['id']}'>";
}
```

И живите себе спокойно.

Comment: Ну человек логику развивает!)

Comment: нуда. получает нужный ИД и потом заново его ищет))) ничего, молодой еще наверное)))

Comment: да ваш вариант в каком то смысле работает но написало оно этот id не в адресной строке а просто эту строчку ниже на странице login.php
< meta http-equiv='Refresh' content='0; URL=index.php?id=1'>

Comment: Все, разобрался, заработало. ))) Вы 

    echo "< meta http-equiv='Refresh' content='0; URL=index.php?id={$id_user['id']}'>"; 

пробел перед meta поставили, который не нужен был, большое спасибо)

Comment: пробел поставил потому что тут редактор текстовой не пропускал этот тег иначе. сори что забыл предупредить. из головы вылетело когда дописал. только обычно вместо мета тега надо юзать вот такое <pre>header ("Location: /index.php?id={$id_user['id']}");</pre>

Comment: да так кстате тоже можно, так даже солиднее смотрится

Comment: так происходит автоматический редирект без выписки ненужного кода в браузер. а то многие еще выписывают вместо мета тегов переход яваскриптом в виде locate=и так далее))

Answer (score 0):

что за переменная $user?

Посмотрите в коде, как объявлена переменная $user и присваивается ей.

Comment: .

    $user = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE login='$login' AND password='$password'");
    $id_user = mysql_fetch_array($user); 

Вот чему объявлена эта переменная, но когда я ставлю в 

    echo "<meta http-equiv='Refresh' content='0; URL=index.php?id=$id_user'>";

в адресной строке пишет id=Array

Comment: в твоем случае не $id\_user = mysql\_fetch\_array($user);
а <pre>
for ($data1=array(); $row=mysql\_fetch\_assoc($resul);$data1[]=$row);
$id_user=$data1х[0];
</pre>

Comment: а вот это <pre>$id_user = $_GET['id'];
$qq = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $user");
$id_user = mysql_fetch_row($user);</pre>
вообще не понимаю зачем тут. у вас есть там и ид и логин зачем еще раз чтото брать из GET и потом чтото непонятное искать по базе и выводить не оформив ничего...